# Clear a cell in a DataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I have an editable datagrid with a dataprovider which is basically Numbers. Is it possible to delete a value? When I do it it puts a 0 in that cell but I really need an empty value, like a Null or a NaN whose are going to be cleaned later with a labelFunction. BTW I also need the cells to keep the 0 if needed to. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign NaN to the value, and create a custom item renderer for your DataGrid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                    clipAndEnableScrolling="true">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void
            {
                if (isNaN(data[column.dataField]))
                    lblData.text = "";
                else
                    lblData.text = Number(data[column.dataField]).toFixed(2);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label id="lblData"
             top="9"
             left="7" />

</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

Comment: I have already applied an itemRenderer to the cells to set some background colors using s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer and I think that the method prepare is not going to fit in that scheme.

Comment: As you didn't specify, I was unsure if you were using Spark or Halo.  Override set data, the concept should still apply.